# Hide reCAPTCHA badge translation

Tags: translation, hide, recaptcha, badge

Can I translate this text "This site is protected by reCAPTCHA and the Google" to Finnish language?
So it could be like in the visible badge in Finnish language:
Suojattu reCAPTCHA-palvelun avulla
Tietosuoja - Ehdot

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq
I'd like to hide the reCAPTCHA badge. What is allowed?
You are allowed to hide the badge as long as you include the reCAPTCHA branding visibly in the user flow. Please include the following text:

This site is protected by reCAPTCHA and the Google
[Privacy Policy](https://policies.google.com/privacy) and
[Terms of Service](https://policies.google.com/terms) apply.

Best Regards,
Tuomo Nurkkala

I didn't try to translate the text, because the instructions say this:
This site is protected by reCAPTCHA and the Google
[Privacy Policy](https://policies.google.com/privacy) and
[Terms of Service](https://policies.google.com/terms) apply.